# React MapView to show address on Marker

Tags: react-native, expo

So I have an app that is getting GPS data from an API.

Is there a way instead of displaying the Lat and Long like I have showing below on the marker, can I get it to show the address?

```
<MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long,
            latitudeDelta: 0.09,
            longitudeDelta: 0.04,
          }}
        >
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: lat,
              longitude: long,
            }}
            title={'Lat: ' + lat + ', Long: ' + long}
          />
        </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Maps and [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) from there